# building javascript timer using setInterval nd EventListeners for the start and rest feature

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, clearinterval

I am working on a timer project with a <kbd>start</kbd> and <kbd>reset</kbd> button and here I have attached my answer but it doesn't work.

Here is the *script.js* that I've written for the timer with a <kbd>start</kbd> and <kbd>reset</kbd> feature (button) the timer value is going to be sitting inside of the h3 tag with a class name of `.timer`.

The timer starts but doesn't stop! Can you please help me to fix it?

```js
const btnStr = document.querySelector(".start-btn");
const btnRst = document.querySelector(".reset-btn");
const btnStp = document.querySelector(".stp-btn");
let timer = document.querySelector(".timer");
let dynamic = 0;

let strtIt = () =>
  setInterval(function() {
    dynamic++;
    timer.innerHTML = `${dynamic}`;
  }, 1000);

btnStr.addEventListener("click", strtIt);

btnRst.addEventListener("click", () => clearInterval(strtIt));
```

```html
<div>
  Time: <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
<button class="start-btn">Start</button>
<button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
<button class="stp-btn">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Please try to use js/html/css snippet whenever possible so we can be clear of the problem you're facing. I've suggested an edit for you as an example for you to learn how to insert them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a variable to store interval. proper implementation should be like this. try clicking `run code snippet`.

```js
const btnStr = document.querySelector(".start-btn");
const btnRst = document.querySelector(".reset-btn");
const btnStp = document.querySelector(".stp-btn");
let timer = document.querySelector(".timer");
let dynamic = 0;
let interval = null;
let strtIt = () => {
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    dynamic++;
    timer.innerHTML = `${dynamic}`;
  }, 1000);
}
let stopIt = () => {
  if (interval) clearInterval(interval)
}


btnStr.addEventListener("click", strtIt);

btnRst.addEventListener("click", stopIt);
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="start-btn">start</button>
  <button class="reset-btn">reset</button>
  <button class="stop-btn">stop</button>
  <div class="timer">timer</div>
</div>
```